# Swift FCM Data Message not received when App is in background (iOS 10)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've looked through every post I could find and read the Firebase Documentation again and again but I can't find the mistake. My App receives FCM data-messages when in the foreground so no problem there. But when the App is running in the background no data is received. It doesn't even show once the app is opened.
The message priority is set to "high" and "content-available" is set to true. I should receive a bunch of IDs.
Here's my AppDelegate Code (mostly from the FCM example code):

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//


import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launched_before") == false {

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)

            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcomeViewController") as! WelcomeViewController

            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        } else {

            // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
            // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
            // [START register_for_notifications]
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

            } else {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }

            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            // [END register_for_notifications]
            FIRApp.configure()


            // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)

        }

        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        print("METHOD 2")

        completionHandler(.newData)
    }


    // [END receive_message]

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return;
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the InstanceID token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.unknown)

        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/substitutions")
        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/debug")
    }

    // [START connect_on_active]
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END connect_on_active]

    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]

    func evaluateRecievedData (remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {

    // Evaluate the data...

    }

}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler(.alert)
    }


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print("USER HAS PRESSED BANNER")

        // Do some stuff...

        completionHandler()
    }

}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {

        print(remoteMessage.appData)

        self.evaluateRecievedData(remoteMessage: remoteMessage)

        print("RECIEVED MESSAGE (FOREGROUND)")

    }

}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

I've activated Push-Notifications and Background Modes: 'Remote notifications' in the Info.plist. Ideally I'd like to process the data in the background and send the user a notification, if it concerns them.

The data sent looks like this:

```
{
  "to": "\/topics\/substitutions",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
    "debug": true,
    "new_ids": [
      7914,
      7915,
      7916,
      7917,
      7918
    ],
    "updated_ids": [

    ]
  }
}
```

I would be ever so grateful if someone knows the solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi. Can you post the actual payload you're sending?

Answer (score 2):

You must add `notification` payload to receive notification in background.

```
{
  "to": "\/topics\/substitutions",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
    "debug": true,
    "new_ids": [
      7914,
      7915,
      7916,
      7917,
      7918
    ],
 "notification":{
      "title":"Sample Title",
      "body":"sample body!"
    }
    "updated_ids": [

    ]
  }
}
```

More information [About FCM Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was what I needed